# JavaScript create element then add it an event

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create an element (without DOM or jQ pls) and then apply it an even... The new created element displays properly and javascript works...

```
var dato = "";
    dato += "<div id='todas'>";
    dato += "<img src=/logos/todos_generos.jpg>";
    dato += "<span>Todas</span>";
    dato += "</div>";

    document.getElementById('generos').innerHTML += dato;
    document.getElementById("todas").onclick = myFunction;


function myFunction(){
alert("This is not working");
}
```

But if later on i add another element using innerHTML also, the previous elements JS would stop working:

```
var dato = "";
    dato += "<div id='someRandom'>";
    dato += "<img src=/logos/todos_generos.jpg>";
    dato += "<span>Todas</span>";
    dato += "</div>";

    document.getElementById('generos').innerHTML += dato;
    document.getElementById("todas").onclick = myFunction;
```

Ive heard innerHTML gives problems on elements already created, this should be done by appending childs but thats just too large to manage properly.

Comment: Why are you doing `+=` for innerHTML? You're not adding anything at that point.

Comment: Just a tip, if you want to avoid headaches from dealing with events for newly created elements, have a read about [event delegation](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [`insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.insertAdjacentHTML), which works similar, but does not disrupt the existing elements:

```
document.getElementById('generos').insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', dato );
```

The way `innerHTML` works is basically:

- get all HTML content as a string
- append your new string
- write the result back as content to the element

When converting the existing elements back to text, you obviously lose all assigned event handlers.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `innerHTML`, it removes all event handlers previously bound to elements. You can use [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.insertAdjacentHTML) method which will preserve events:

```
var dato = "";
    dato += "<div id='someRandom'>";
    dato += "<img src=/logos/todos_generos.jpg>";
    dato += "<span>Todas</span>";
    dato += "</div>";

document.getElementById('generos').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', dato);
```

Another solution is to manually append new elements using [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild) method but this is more verbose:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = dato;
document.getElementById('generos').appendChild(div);
```